# When I use the apple to log in, the selection box will pop up. I choose to use the password to continue and the prompt is not complete

Tags: ios, ios13

iOS13 (beta) Apple Login error

```
@available(iOS 13.0, *)
    func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithError error: Error) {
        // Handle error.
        crprint(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

Failed to complete operation. (com.apple.AuthenticationServices.AuthorizationError error 1000.)

Answer (score 8):

I've encountered the same issue yesterday and I've managed to fix it following these steps:

1. Go to https://appleid.apple.com/account/manage, under the `Devices` section you should find devices on which you are signed in with your Apple ID,
2. Find device/simulator on which Apple SSO is not working, click on it and click remove from the account,
3. Go back to your device/simulator settings, it will ask you to authenticate again. When you successfully authenticate, Apple SSO should **work** again!

I'm not sure what caused this issue, probably some issue between the simulator and Apple ID.

Comment: Thanks man, you saved me. Apple Sign in is the worst thing I have done in 2020. Now everything is sorted.

Answer (score 4):

In my case i needed to first check `ASAuthorizationPasswordProvider`, then, if there are no stored credential, use `ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider`. For this case i had to make some crunches. Code below:

```
// Initial point   
public func fire(appleIDCompletion: @escaping AppleIDServiceCompletion) {
    self.completion = appleIDCompletion

    let requestPassword = ASAuthorizationPasswordProvider().createRequest()
    performRequest(requestPassword)
}

// help function
private func performRequest(_ request: ASAuthorizationRequest) {
    let controller = ASAuthorizationController(authorizationRequests: [request])
    controller.delegate = self
    controller.presentationContextProvider = self
    controller.performRequests()
} 

// delegate
func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithError error: Error) {
    if let e = error as? ASAuthorizationError {
        switch e.code {
        case .canceled:
            trace("User did cancel authorization.")
            return
        case .failed:
            trace("Authorization failed.")
        case .invalidResponse:
            trace("Authorization returned invalid response.")
        case .notHandled:
            trace("Authorization not handled.")
        case .unknown:
            if controller.authorizationRequests.contains(where: { $0 is ASAuthorizationPasswordRequest }) {
                trace("Unknown error with password auth, trying to request for appleID auth..")

                let requestAppleID = ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider().createRequest()
                requestAppleID.requestedScopes = [.email, .fullName]
                requestAppleID.requestedOperation = .operationImplicit
                performRequest(requestAppleID)
                return
            } else {
                trace("Unknown error for appleID auth.")
            }
        default:
            trace("Unsupported error code.")
        }
    }

    completion?(.rejected(error))
}
```

Works like a charm

Comment: Very Helpful very interesting. It covered everything Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In my case, launching `ASAuthorizationController` including a request for `ASAuthorizationPasswordProvider` was causing the error.

> Failed to complete operation. (com.apple.AuthenticationServices.AuthorizationError error 1000.)

---

From the [`ASAuthorizationError.Code` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/asauthorizationerror/code); `1000` is for `unknown`

> **ASAuthorizationError.Code.unknown**
>
> The authorization attempt failed for an unknown reason.
>
> **Declaration**
>
> ```
> case unknown = 1000
> ```
>
> <sub>Ref: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/asauthorizationerror/code/unknown</sub>

Now that's not particularly helpful but did give me a clue to check my `ASAuthorizationController` setup which I was trying to launch with 2 requests from `ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider` & `ASAuthorizationPasswordProvider`, like so:

```
func loginWithAppleButtonPressed() {
    let appleSignInRequest = ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider().createRequest()
    appleSignInRequest.requestedScopes = [.fullName, .email]

    let anySignInRequest = ASAuthorizationPasswordProvider().createRequest()

    let controller = ASAuthorizationController(authorizationRequests: [appleSignInRequest, 
                                                                       anySignInRequest])
    controller.delegate = self
    controller.presentationContextProvider = self

    controller.performRequests()
}
```

I tried this on a simulator that had an Apple ID with 2FA enabled and also on a device with another Apple ID without 2FA, and both times it would just go to `authorizationController(controller:didCompleteWithError error:)` and that's it.

---

### Solution:

So to keep it simple, I launched `ASAuthorizationController` with only `ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider` like so:

```
func loginWithAppleButtonPressed() {
    let appleSignInRequest = ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider().createRequest()
    appleSignInRequest.requestedScopes = [.fullName, .email]

    let controller = ASAuthorizationController(authorizationRequests: [appleSignInRequest])
    controller.delegate = self
    controller.presentationContextProvider = self

    controller.performRequests()
}
```

And voilà! This time things worked as expected:

1. When using an Apple ID with 2FA

   - popped up with the login request
2. When using an Apple ID without 2FA

   - popped up an error telling me to enable 2FA
   - called `authorizationController(controller:didCompleteWithError error:)` with `error 1000`

---

So seems that in my case `ASAuthorizationPasswordProvider` was the culprit but since `ASAuthorizationError.Code.unknown` is a generic error case, this solution may not work for you.

Also, In my case I need only `ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider` for Apple ID sign in so dropped the support for `ASAuthorizationPasswordProvider`.

Comment: func loginWithAppleButtonPressed() {
    let appleSignInRequest = ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider().createRequest()
    appleSignInRequest.requestedScopes = [.fullName, .email]

    let controller = ASAuthorizationController(authorizationRequests: [appleSignInRequest])
    controller.delegate = self
    controller.presentationContextProvider = self

    controller.performRequests()
}

Comment: I also use it like this, I didn't modify it, but now the problem disappears, oh, but I have done nothing.

Comment: If I don't use `ASAuthorizationPasswordProvider`, how will I be able to retrieve credentials for the app?

Comment: I had issue with this too then I figured out that ASAuthorizationPasswordProvider will only show result if there is any available login info already saved. So you should just call this method on ViewDidLoad and if there is any login info then it will show (tested on real device). If lets say no info available then on user tapping the Sign In Button, you should just pass ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider and shouldn't pass ASAuthorizationPasswordProvider. I think this is the intended flow, documentation is not very clear about this.

Answer (score 2):

Simply Add +  "Sign In with Apple" from Capability.

Answer (score 1):

I've resolved it by adding `sign in with apple as` key in  entitlements plist .

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From Apple's example,

`performExistingAccountSetupFlows`, only call this method once on viewDidAppear. If user info exists already then Apple will show it to login. If not then it will throw error.

`handleAuthorizationAppleIDButtonPress`, whenever user taps on `Sign in with Apple` button, note that if an account already had existed it would have shown it to the user already. I believe its still in progress and not all use cases are covered, for example if user sees the login info initially from ViewDidAppear call and cancels it then user have to create a new account when tapping on this method since its missing `ASAuthorizationPasswordProvider` request. If user had some login info then in that case this call (with `ASAuthorizationPasswordProvider`) will succeed but if no data is available then user will not see any action on tapping this button since it will throw error.

I am still figuring this out, if I have anything more to add then I will update the answer. So, for now we can only have this one use case to use this `Sign in with Apple` option.

**Update:**
Once I created a new account, I was offered by this same flow to login with the already existing account. So, I can say that there is no need to include call to `ASAuthorizationPasswordProvider` request in `handleAuthorizationAppleIDButtonPress` method. I am doing all the testing on device.

You can always go to `Settings -> AppleId -> Password & Security -> Apple ID Logins` to check and delete account if you need to test various scenarios.

**Update 2:**
Everything seems to work fine in other scenarios too if you already have a saved password or App Id account created, so even if I pass ASAuthorizationPasswordProvider in the `handleAuthorizationAppleIDButtonPress` call, it is working fine. I would suggest to not pass `ASAuthorizationPasswordProvider` in the next call and keep the flow as described above, this way if no saved password is present or Apple Id created then it will provide option to the user to create a new id, if there is already an id that exists then it will show that id.

```
 override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        performExistingAccountSetupFlows()
    }

    func performExistingAccountSetupFlows() {
        // Prepare requests for both Apple ID and password providers.
        let requests = [ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider().createRequest(),
                        ASAuthorizationPasswordProvider().createRequest()]

        // Create an authorization controller with the given requests.
        let authorizationController = ASAuthorizationController(authorizationRequests: requests)
        authorizationController.delegate = self
        authorizationController.presentationContextProvider = self
        authorizationController.performRequests()
    }

    @objc
    func handleAuthorizationAppleIDButtonPress() {
        let appleIDProvider = ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider()
        let request = appleIDProvider.createRequest()
        request.requestedScopes = [.fullName, .email]

        let authorizationController = ASAuthorizationController(authorizationRequests: [request])
        authorizationController.delegate = self
        authorizationController.presentationContextProvider = self
        authorizationController.performRequests()
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this by holding my finger down on finger print scanner til completion.  I'm not an iphone user so I'm not used to the finger print scanner.  If you pull your finger off too soon you get this error.

Comment: Well, I'd narrowed this down to iTouch being the issue...but still no luck.

And, incredibly, this was it!    A day wasted juggling devices trying to solve this - because a quick tap would close the prompt as expected...but then fail, whilst an iPhone X with broken face ID (which required manual unlock) worked perfectly!   Good example of even the most ridiculous solutions are useful to someone - this time me!  Thanks!